# Max lifetime of transactions in mempool?

Tags: transactions, mempool

If a transaction sits a long time in the tezos mempool for a reason or another does it get eventually cleaned-up or will it stay there forever ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the current protocol there's a time to live of 60 blocks for every manager operation, after which they can no longer be included.

Answer (score 2):

**NB:** After the adoption of the [Granada protocol](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/010_granada.html), which halves the minimal time between blocks, the `max_operation_ttl` constant was doubled from `60` to `120` blocks, to roughly preserve the length of the live blocks and operations window when measured in wall-clock time.

**NB NB** After the activation of the [Mumbai protocol upgrade](https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/Mumbai-is-live.html) further halved minimal blocktime from 30s to 15s, this constant was consequently doubled, again, from `120` to `240` blocks to preserve the invariant.