# Does an operation in the mempool expire after 60 or 64 blocks?

Tags: mempool

Ive seen some conflicting answers saying [64 blocks](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/speeding-up-cancelling-transactions-stuck-in-mempool) or [60 blocks](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/104/max-lifetime-of-transactions-in-mempool)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right answer is **60 at the moment**, as answered in:

[Max lifetime of transactions in mempool?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/104/max-lifetime-of-transactions-in-mempool)

This value is set by the protocol-dependent constant `max_operations_ttl` in:

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/alpha_context.ml#L261

Thus, **it can eventually change** on future versions of the protocol.

Notice also that 60 is an upper bound: the current implementation of the mempool performs a recycling process each time the node changes its head, and incompatible operations are discarded.

**EDIT**: This reply is outdated, as the adoption of the Granada protocol changed `max_operation_ttl` to **120** blocks. However, notice that given the halving of the minimal time within blocks from 60 to 30 seconds, the window still has a similar length, when measured in *human* time units, i.e. ~1h.