# Is it still not possible to update or cancel a tx in the Tezos Mempool

Tags: transactions, operation, mempool

As of ~1.5 years ago, this wasn't possible: https://twitter.com/dsintermediatd/status/1286341689368551428

I am wondering if there is any way to do this now and if so whether or not anybody has built this into an SDK.

Thanks

Comment: NB: The **64** block limit in the mentioned Twitter thread is incorrect. The value of the protocol-dependent constant `max_operations_ttl` is  `120 blocks` in the current protocol. See, e.g., https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/104/max-lifetime-of-transactions-in-mempool/3710#3710, fore more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RPC to ban/remove an operation (The endpoint should be protected with an ACL for safety reasons).

The RPC endpoint is **POST** [/chains/main/mempool/ban_operation](https://mainnet.api.tez.ie/describe/chains/main/mempool/ban_operation) (This link includes the endpoint specification).

https://tezos.gitlab.io/CHANGES.html?highlight=ban_operation#version-11-0-rc1

> The operation is removed from the mempool, and its effect is reverted
> if it was applied. It is also added to the prevalidator’s set of
> banned operations, to prevent it from being fetched/processed/injected
> in the future.

It is also possible to clear the operations in the mempool by restarting the node used to inject the operation. (Not great)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from `Octez v12.0`, a **replace by fees feature** will be available on the Octez shell implementation:

- https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/3968

This will enable the user to replace a manager operation in the Octez prevalidator's mempool (valid or not), for another manager operation - which either has more declared fees, or a greater fee/gas ratio.

However, this Octez feature depends on new protocol functionality (notably, *operations precheck*) which was included in [the Ithaca protocol proposal](https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/announcing-tezos-9th-protocol-upgrade-proposal-ithaca.html), and hence it is not supported by [Hangzhou](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/011_hangzhou.html), the current protocol of Tezos mainnet.

This feature will then only become operational once/if Ithaca (or another protocol implementing this functionality) is adopted by the community.

**NB** that the replacement operation might have the same payload, but it might very well not: for instance a possible use of this feature is to extend a batch of manager operations with a new operation.